# How can I use a custom compressed file format for my APKs?

Tags: android, compression, apk

In Facebook's [Superpack article](https://engineering.fb.com/2021/09/13/core-data/superpack/), they discuss using a custom compressed format for their APKs. I want to use a custom format as well, but how can I tell Android how to decompress my APKs?

Comment: My interpretation of that article is that the APKs are normal. What Facebook/Meta/Whatever is doing is optimizing the artifacts put into the APK for better representations as compressed artifacts.

Comment: @CommonsWare I interpreted it a different way, that they are custom compressing different artifacts included the APKs and can control how those artifacts are decompressed on install on device. In theory, you could specify `uncompressedGlob` files to bundletool from [these docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundleconfig) which you could theoretically compress using more aggressive compression, assuming you could control how to decompress those on device.

Comment: @CommonsWare indeed this is what I'm wondering

Comment: AFAIK, that would require modifications to Android itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare then how is Facebook doing this, as they claim to be?